# pip3 ImportError: cannot import name 'IncompleteRead'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Having trouble installing modules via `pip3`, tried several suggestions from top voted thread from Dec' 2014, but still getting the following:

```
sudo pip3 install send2trash
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name 'IncompleteRead'
```

On Ubuntu 15.10; tried removing python 3 completely and reinstalling, still having issues. Help?

Edit: UPDATE: Tried using my bootable USB to repair Ubuntu and get back to original config and reinstalled via sudo apt-get install python3-pip, but now it generates a crash report saying:

```
Sorry, the application pip3 has unexpectedly crashed.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This seems to be an issue with pip's interaction with the `requests` package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1306991). `requests` dropped the `IncompleteRead` module but older versions of pip, which you have, still rely on it, newer versions don't.

You should try updating `pip` via `easy_install-3.5` (if you have `Python 3.5`) or `easy_install-3` for other versions:

```
sudo easy_install-3.5 -U pip
```

or:

```
sudo easy_install-3 -U pip
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Tried putting my results in here, but having trouble, sudo easy_install3 -U pip successfully completed, but now I get an Exception and traceback with a permission denied error when I run pip install <module>

Comment: With fresh install of Ubuntu and initial failure with install of python3-pip, followed up with apt-get install python3-requests and then sudo easy_install3 -U pip and SUCCESS!

Comment: easy_install3 worked for me but easy_install-3 did not

Comment: Wha tis the line for windows?

Answer (score 3):

Had similar error on Raspberry Pi. The solution was a combination of all proposals above:

```
 sudo pip install --upgrade pip
 sudo pip install --upgrade requests
 sudo easy_install3 -U pip
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened me when I tried to install a pip module to my Python3 installation. I mistakenly run `pip` instead of `pip3` and it installed Python2 modules into Python3 installation. After that I realized command was wrong, I run `pip3` this time. But, it was no good, installation was blown up, there were errors in Python2 like parenthesis missing in print statement(obviously this is an error for Python3). Eventually, it blown up my terminal too, I needed to install another terminal.

Like you did, I tried to install and reinstall everything, but it didn't work. Fix needed to be done manually. After trying several days and failing, I backed up my files and reinstalled Ubuntu.

I know this is not what you want, but maybe you can save your time by accepting that reinstalling the OS is the easiest solution.

Comment: I tried re-installing to repair the Ubuntu installation and now am getting a message that says that says "Sorry, the application pip3 has stopped unexpectedly" and sends off a crash report. Unfortunately I can't copy the details.

Comment: I mean fresh install the OS. Format partition, and install OS again.

Comment: Ok, fresh install complete, installed python3-pip, began using pip3 and installed 2 modules and it broke on the 3rd and I got a repeat of the crash report. I haven't mistakenly installed pip instead of pip3 this time, so issue must be originating from something else??

Comment: If you didn't try to install Python2 mods on Python3 or vice-versa, then yes, issue should be something else. Maybe the module you want to install malfunctions? Or installation script is broken maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install newest versions of pip and requests:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade requests
```